# How to access coordinates in Python Streamlit Folium map after clicking on Popup?

Tags: python, streamlit, folium

I have a map in Python Folium. I want to put the location in coordinates of a popup after it is clicked into a Python variable, so that I can access it to display it using st.write(), and also do some more stuff with it after that using information I have for the location in a dataframe.

Here is what I have tried, but when I try to st.write(result) in another function, I get error saying result is not defined. How do I resolve it, or is there a better way to do solve what I hope to achieve above in an easier or different way?

```
map = folium.Map(location=[38,-96.5], zoom_start=4)
    
    df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    cords = df[["lat","lon"]]
    cord_list = cords.values.tolist()
    
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        row = df.iloc[i]
        name = row["name"]
        date = row["date"]
        city = row["city"]
        state = row["state"]
        
        pop=folium.Popup(f"""<input type="text" value="{cord_list[i][0]}, {cord_list[i][1]}"{name} id="location"> <br>
                       {date} <br>
                       {city}, {state} <br>
                       <button onclick="myFunction()">Show More</button>
                    """, max_width=len(f"name= {name}")*7)
        
        folium.Marker(cord_list[i], popup=pop).add_to(map)
    
    el = folium.MacroElement().add_to(map)
    el._template = jinja2.Template("""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
        function myFunction() {
          /* Get the text field */
          var copyText = document.getElementById("location");

          /* Select the text field */
          copyText.select();
          copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
          
          /* Copy the text inside the text field */
          var result = document.execCommand("copy");
          {{ custom_function(result) }}
          

        }
        {% endmacro %}
    """)
    el._template.globals['custom_function'] = custom_function
    
    i_map = st_folium(map, width=700, height=450)
```

I was expecting to be able to use result in the Python function custom_function, but it didn't work and I got an error.

[How to copy a marker's location on folium Map by clicking on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67628175/how-to-copy-a-markers-location-on-folium-map-by-clicking-on-it)

This example copies it and is what my code is modeled on, but I am not sure how to get it into a Python variable which is my goal to access the coordinates.

Comment: You mentioned "when I try to st.write(result) in another function, I get error saying result is not defined" -- it sounds like you're defining it in one function and trying to reference it from another function. Instead, you can store the value in st.session_state or a global variable. https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state