# Python folium - failed with extending functionality

Tags: python, folium

I would like to extend the functionality of my folium map

I found a nice thread here:

[Python: How to extend Folium functionality (such as measuring distance) by using JS Leaflet inside python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774249/python-how-to-extend-folium-functionality-such-as-measuring-distance-by-using)

but it doesn't work when apply to my code

```
 export_js = [
     (
        "leaflet_bigimage_js",
        "js/Leaflet.BigImage.js",
     )
  ]

 export_css = [
    (
        "leaflet_bigimage_css",
        "css/Leaflet.BigImage.css",
    )
 ]

 exp = folium.MacroElement()
 exp.template = jinja2.Template("""
 {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
 L.control.bigImage({position: 'topright'}).addTo{map}
 {% endmacro %}
 """)
 map.get_root().add_child(exp)
```

the map works, but the element doesn't appear at all. Moreover, JS console sees nothing.

Is there any way how could I sort it out?

UPDATE:

I tried also:

```
 class exp(MacroElement):
exp_template = Template(u"""
{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
L.control.bigImage({position: 'topright'}).addTo({{ 
 this._parent.get_name() }})
{% endmacro %}
""")
 map.add_child(exp())
```

but with the same result

Answer (score 0):

If you have the css and js files on the computer, you can use the `branca` library, that gets installed with `folium` to include the js and css elements.

```
import folium
from branca.element import CssLink, JavascriptLink
from pathlib import Path

js_file = Path("/path/to/script.js")
js_link = JavascriptLink(js_file.as_uri())

css_file = Path("/path/to/style.css")
css_link = CssLink(css_file.as_uri())

map = folium.Map()
html = map.get_root()
header = html.header

#Add links
header.add_child(css_link)
header.add_child(js_link)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be done this way:
line 761, in as_uri
    raise ValueError("relative path can't be expressed as a file URI")
ValueError: relative path can't be expressed as a file URI

Comment: What OS are you using and can you give an example how are you declaring `js_file` variable.